# How to dump out the entire contents of Master DB in SQL Server, as TSQL

Tags: sql-server

I need a large amount of MS-dialect SQL to test a parser against. I thought the master DB might be a good place to get some (possibly Model too) or just the system objects (procs, funcs, tables - the lot) in a user DB (copy of Model, really). The graphical wizard (right click on db) -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts... don't seem to allow a dump of System objects in the DB. I even backed up master and restored as a 'normal' db; still no luck.

I assume it's to do with flag is_ms_shipped, which can be set with `sp_MS_marksystemobject`, but I can't see a way to undo or bypass this.
Maybe there's a way of rebuilding master from some (human-readable) TSQL I'm unaware of?

A script to dump them would be even better. Any suggestions please? It's purely for internal use, so no abuse of IP.

Edit: I'm talking about schema objects not actual data in tables.

Comment: Just a thought, but rather than messing with the system databases, why not use the AdventureWorks DB... http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yeah dumping master is a complete and total no-no. It can and will break so many underlying things that you don't seem to be aware of. Dumping any system DBs even on test and Dev can have serious reprecutions. Like @dwjv said go online and find a .BAK file of adventure works or somehting similar and then mess with that one.

Comment: I need a *lot* of data, and AdventureWorks is certainly on my list too, however it's not all that large (schema-wise) or interesting/complex. Master has a lot of schema, complexity, and some oddities. If you can suggest any other userDBs (I've got Northwind) please do - I will need more - lots more!

Comment: @Wes Palmer: dumping master to TSQL is utterly harmless - I'm not removing or altering it, just need its schema to examine (parse).

Comment: If you're looking for a quantity of data, then master is a poor choice.  It's not very big at all.  I've got a server with about a dozen 30 GB databases, and master is still about 6 MB... so there isn't a whole lot to the database.  My understanding was that a lot of the system procedures are either intentionally hidden (not just marked as system) or refer to external libraries or internal functions.  There's quite literally nothing useful to see.  If you want you could back up the database COPY_ONLY and then restore it to a new user database, but beware that might not work all that well.

Comment: @Bacon Bits: it's not data it's schema; tables, procs, funcs (I'll amend the main post to emphasise this). As mentioned, I did try the backup/restore as a new db, and the is_ms_shipped flags went with it so no jam there.

Comment: Well, if you're just looking for stuff that's schema complex, then you could grab one of the open source student information systems, ERP systems. or hospital information systems.  Or you can truly gaze into the abyss and have a look at [SharePoint](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-RTM-Trial-9e198fec).

Comment: @Bacon Bits: did look for some FOSS stuff but must have missed it. Will try again. Thanks for sharepoint link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want sp, fn, views, etc... start with

```
USE master
GO
SELECT object_name(object_id), definition, * FROM sys.system_sql_modules
GO
```

If you just want everything

```
USE master
GO
SELECT Object_Name(id), text, * from sys.syscomments
GO
```

Tweak the queries as needed to filter to the specific objects you need.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of catalog views - thanks!

Comment: Interesting, but it looks like a lot of things are hidden, ultimately.  `sys.objects` is just `SELECT <field_list> FROM sys.objects$`, for example.  You can also just use the `object_definition()` function.

Comment: @Bacon Bits: agreed it looks like some stuff isn't there, but it's a good start. I'll see how `object_definition()` behaves too. `system_sql_modules` seems to be the recommended successor to syscomments`; the latter breaks its defs into nvarchar(4000) chunks. Accounting for that they have approximately the same number of entries, but not quite. Will dig. Thanks to everyone.